# How to search and return json object?

Tags: javascript, json, find

I need to search and return a json object children, following the json children value.

here is a working code I have written (bring back the right object):

```
const sites = [
  {
    name: "Lightinthebox WW",
    site_url: "https://lightinthebox.com/",
    domain: "lightinthebox.com",
  },
  {
    name: "Aliexpress WW",
    site_url: "https://aliexpress.com/",
    domain: "aliexpress.com",
  },
  {
    name: "Dx WW",
    site_url: "http://dx.com/",
    domain: "dx.com",
  }
];

var site = "aliexpress.com";
const foundSite = sites.find(s => site.includes(s.domain)); 
//return: {name: "Aliexpress WW", site_url: "https://aliexpress.com/",    domain: "aliexpress.com"}
```

now, I have a different JSON:

```
const sites = {"All":{"5631":{"id":5631,"name":"Lightinthebox WW","site_url":"https:\/\/lightinthebox.com\/","domain":"lightinthebox.com"},"6115":{"id":6115,"name":"Aliexpress WW","site_url":"https:\/\/aliexpress.com\/","domain":"aliexpress.com"},"7077":{"id":7077,"name":"Dx WW","site_url":"http:\/\/dx.com\/","domain":"dx.com","13318":{"id":13318,"name":"GearBest WW","site_url":"https:\/\/gearbest.com\/","domain":"gearbest.com"}}};
```

I tried to do the same and I have "sites.find is not a function"

Can you see why? Tried to search for a way to bring back the right object (search for domain:"aliexpress.com" then bring back all object "{"id":6115,"name":"Aliexpress WW","site_url":"https://aliexpress.com/","domain":"aliexpress.com"}")

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string format. Once you parse it back to an object with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), you just have a regular old object.

Comment: It's a JSON object, no need to parse as it's not a string, what am I missing?

Comment: Again, there's no such thing as a JSON object. JSON is a string, an object is an object.

Comment: Your issue is simply that `.find()` is an Array method and so your first example works. But your second example is an Object and objects don't have a `.find()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is an array method which is available on `sites` in your first example because it is an array, but in your second attempt you are trying to call it on an object.

In this case you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to return an array of value objects within the `All` property of the top level object and use `.find()` on that.

(this is not [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) related, but knowing the methods available for the class you are dealing with; [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) vs [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) in this case)

```js
const sites = {
  "All": {
    "5631": {
      "id": 5631, "name": "Lightinthebox WW", "site_url": "https:\/\/lightinthebox.com\/", "domain": "lightinthebox.com"
    },
    "6115": {
      "id": 6115, "name": "Aliexpress WW", "site_url": "https:\/\/aliexpress.com\/", "domain": "aliexpress.com"
    },
    "7077": {
      "id": 7077, "name": "Dx WW", "site_url": "http:\/\/dx.com\/", "domain": "dx.com"
    },
    "13318": {
      "id": 13318, "name": "GearBest WW", "site_url": "https:\/\/gearbest.com\/", "domain": "gearbest.com"
    }
  }
};

const site = "aliexpress.com";
const foundSite = Object.values(sites.All).find(s => site.includes(s.domain));

console.log(foundSite);
```